# Relations and quantifiers

Tags: relations, propositional-calculus

When talking about relations, we know that the relation is anti-symmetric if 
"for all x: for all y: R(x,y) AND R(y,x) IMPLIES (x=y)". But can i rewrite this as "for all x: for all y: R(x,y) EXCLUSIVE OR R(y,x)"?
Because don't both of them mean "no 2 way arrows"?

Comment: Exclusive or makes $R(x,x)$ always false.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: So what if I add an OR saying, " for all x: for all y: R(x,y) EXCLUSIVE OR R(y,x) OR R(x,x)"?

Comment: Similar problem. Suppose we have a nice partial order with three dangling items $a,b,c$ that are not related to each other or themselves. Then the exclusive or combination is false, but the implication version is true.

Comment: Oh it's kind of confusing but I get it.. Thanks!